# "Could not find service for user" while setting up dreamfactory on laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, dreamfactory

while i try to setup dream factory in laravel.It gives error as:

```
Could not find service for user
```

Also in browser console it shows error as:

```
XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience
```

.Please some body help me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two issues going on. I might be able to help with the DreamFactory one.

Try making sure (in your admin console) that your authorized user has a default role assigned. (Tap your application in the "apps" tab and there is a drop down for default role on the right).

Then ensure that user role has access to your services (In the roles tab, tap the role and then go to the access tab).

This "cannot find service" error can happen when the user role making the request does not have the needed permission for the service.

The second error is about the way you are making the request.  It looks like you need to execute XMLHttpRequest on a background thread.  Seems the second error is not actually preventing the DreamFactory API request.  Just warning that it's not the ideal way to make it.

Hope this info helps.